# How to restore the recovery partition in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, recovery-partition

I had to clone my hard drive from a bigger one to a smaller one and in the process I lost the recovery partition that was at the end of the hard drive. It was a 500MB partition. I'm running the latest version of Windows 10. Is it possible to restore that partition?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/802845/restore-deleted-windows-8-1-recovery-partition?rq=1) is a 90% solution.  The only difference is that you need to use the Windows 10 SDK instead of the Windows 8 Evaluation Kit.

Comment: You can live without the recovery partition. You can use the Windows 10 download to reinstall Windows and then update any drivers it did not update.

Comment: If you can still access the old drive, try to resize the big one smaller before the clone so it might fit.  Thats what I would *try* .. :|  What @John says is true but I too like having the recovery partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 lacks partitions and WinRe options](https://superuser.com/a/1514869/529800). If the `winre.wim` doesn't exist within `%WinDir%\System32\Recovery`, use the Windows Media Creation Tool to download the Windows 10 install ISO, open `sources\install.esd` within [7zip](https://7-zip.org/), choose folder `1` for Home or `6` for Pro, navigate to `Windows\System32\Recovery`, and extract `winre.wim`. From there, proceed with the steps in the aforementioned answer. **Note:** there are different WinRE partition creation steps depending if you have BIOS or UEFI

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of the process of restoring recovery partition on Windows 10, if there is no recovery partition at all. In addition, I suggest, if there is one which is not functioning then delete the partition/volume and redo from scratch. Use with caution! Using only Microsoft tools, so one can be 100% sure there is no security issue.

1. Download & Create Microsoft Windows ISO for your system https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 or ...windows11.
2. Create `C:\wim` and `C:\wim\install`

   ```
    mkdir c:\wim
    mkdir c:\wim\install
   ```
3. Mount the ISO image or use the DVD; locate `\sources\install.esd` file and copy to `C:\wim`
4. List all the versions:

   ```
    Dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:c:\wim\install.esd

    ...
    ...
    Index : 4
    Name : Windows 10 Education
    Description : Windows 10 Education
    Size : 15,613,170,917 bytes

    Index : 5
    Name : Windows 10 Education N
    Description : Windows 10 Education N
    Size : 14,857,698,925 bytes

    Index : 6
    Name : Windows 10 Pro
    Description : Windows 10 Pro
    Size : 15,625,575,440 bytes
    ...
    ...
   ```
5. Extract `install.wim` for your system - have 15GB free space

   ```
    Dism /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:C:\wim\install.esd /SourceIndex:6 /DestinationImageFile:C:\WIM\install.wim /Compress:max /CheckIntegrity

    ...
    ...
    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.19041.3636

    Exporting image
    [==========================100.0%==========================]
    The operation completed successfully.
    ...
    ...
   ```
6. Get info from the extracted `C:\wim\install.wim`

   ```
    Dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:c:\wim\install.wim

    ...
    ...
    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.19041.3636

    Details for image : c:\wim\install.wim

    Index : 1
    Name : Windows 10 Home
    Description : Windows 10 Home
    Size : 15,276,446,585 bytes

    Index : 2
    Name : Windows 10 Pro
    Description : Windows 10 Pro
    Size : 15,625,575,440 bytes

    The operation completed successfully.
    ...
    ...
   ```
7. Decompress files

   ```
    Dism /apply-image /imagefile:c:\wim\install.wim /index:2 /ApplyDir:c:\wim\install
   ```
8. Locate `C:\wim\install\windows\system32\recovery\Winre.wim` and copy (for clarity only) to `C:\wim`, the `Winre.wim` is the only file needed. You can delete all else created in the process from disk.
9. Check the `Winre.wim`

   ```
    Dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:c:\wim\winre.wim

    ...
    ...
    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.19041.3636

    Details for image : c:\wim\winre.wim

    Index : 1
    Name : Microsoft Windows Recovery Environment (x64)
    Description : Microsoft Windows Recovery Environment (x64)
    Size : 2,244,440,228 bytes

    The operation completed successfully.
    ...
    ...
   ```
10. Necessary disk operations (explaining each step is over the scope of this contribution, as it would become a book - research every step!) if you do not know what each command does do not continue!

    ```
    diskpart
    list disk

    ...
    ...
    Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
    --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
    Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB        *
    ...
    ...


    select disk 1

    ...
    ... 
    Disk 1 is now the selected disk.
    ... 
    ...

    list volume

    ...
    Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
    ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
    ...
    ...

    select volume 2

    ...
    ...
    Volume 2 is the selected volume.
    ...
    ...

    shrink desired=1500
    create partition primary
    format quick fs=ntfs
    assign letter=r
    ```
11. Create directory `R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\`

    ```
    mkdir R:\Recovery\
    mkdir R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\
    ```
12. Copy the image `C:\wim\Winre.wim` to `R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\`
13. Set GUID for the partition to mark it as "Recovery" type.

    ```
    diskpart
    list disk
    select disk 1
    list partition
    select part 4
    set id=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
    ```
14. Set RE image

    ```
    reagentc /setreimage /path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\

    ...
    ...    
    Directory set to: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition4\Recovery\WindowsRE

    REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.
    ...
    ...
    ```
15. Remove the leter from volume

    ```
    diskpart
    list disk
    select disk 1
    list volume
    select volume 5
    remove letter=R
    ```
16. Re-enable the "Recovery" system

    ```
    reagentc /enable

    ...
    ...
    REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.
    ...
    ...
    ```

That concludes the process. The recovery partition is not necessary for the OS to function. The process is possible to repeat. I suggest to test the process for any version of Windows first in a virtual environment. It has been slightly different in past and one can assume it will be so in future.

Comment: I'd add that if you already are in a virtual environment, take a snapshot first (maybe even start with a clone).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the current state of your Windows recovery: `reagentc /info`
2. Create an empty 1GB partition in the end of your system drive.

   - You might need to shrink your previous partition to free some space. If Windows Disk Manager would be unable to shrink it, use [GParted live USB](https://gparted.org/livecd.php).
3. Mark partition type as recovery `27` for BIOS/MBR (or `DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC` for UEFI/GPT). In cmd: `diskpart`, `list disk` `select disk 0`, `list part`, `sel part 3`, `det part`, `set id=27`, `exit`.

   - This just an example, make sure to select the correct partition!
4. Disable and enable Recovery to move it to the new partition: `reagentc /disable`, `reagentc /enable`.
5. Verify that Recovery is now on the new partition: `reagentc /info`

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlNtLcFqfOo&t)'s a nice video guide.

Comment: There is _never_ a need to use a Linux-based utility to configure WinRE _(please see `shrink` in `diskpart`)_, and `id=27` is for BIOS only, UEFI requires entirely different steps

Comment: I personally ran into the inability to shrink my OS partition from Windows itself yesterday. Not sure why, but this was not the [unmovable files issue](https://www.easeus.com/amp/partition-manager-software/windows-cant-shrink-volume-partition.html). Thanks for noting that GPT recovery partition ID is different, I fixed this